# CSS rules not overridden with another rules after them

Tags: css

I have the following code both in two CSS tiles with different values (using LESS).
The CSS is linked in link tag in the header. The `all.css` is positioned before the `override.css`. The problem is that when I browse the site, I can't see any changes and it only uses the code in the `all.css` instead of overriding it with the one in `override.css`.

```
#subheader h1 {
font-size: 3vw;

@media screen and (max-width: 39.9375em) {
    font-size: 3vw;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    font-size: 3vw;
    ;
}
/* Large and up */
@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
    font-size: 3vw;

}
}
```

How can I make so that the rules override without using `!important`?

There is no problem with the LESS compilation and it results in a correct CSS file, this is why I have no idea why it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using completely wrong syntax of writing css `@media` rule. Follow this [w3schools link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp), the correct syntax should be:

```css
@media not|only mediatype and (media feature and|or|not mediafeature) {
    CSS-Code;
}
```

The correct code will be:

```css
#subheader h1 {
  font-size: 3vw;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 39.9375em) {
  #subheader h1 {
    font-size: 3vw;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  #subheader h1 {
    font-size: 3vw;
  }
}

/* Large and up */
@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
  #subheader h1 {
    font-size: 3vw;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
#subheader h1 {
font-size: 3vw;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 39.9375em) {
    font-size: 3vw;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    font-size: 3vw;
    ;
}
/* Large and up */
@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
    font-size: 3vw;
}
```